# Google Chrome keep crashing in macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have Google Chrome and it keeps crashing immediately 5-10 seconds after I open it, with no error message. I tried to restart the computer and re-install several times but it didn't work. What can be the reason?

I am using an iMac, running macOS Catalina, 10.15.7.
It crashes for all Chrome versions (as it happens even when I reinstall the latest). I don't have a list of extensions since I can't open or use Chrome. Therefore I also can check it on another account.

Using AppCleaner, I get this:

[image]

However, I don't want to lose my bookmarks, saved passwords, etc.
Which of these boxes should I check in order to uninstall the app but keep the data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tetsujin See the edit

Comment: We still don't have all the info asked for, & we now have two separate questions - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322935/where-are-google-chrome-bookmarks-stored-in-macos-for-multiple-profiles

Comment: @Tetsujin So from my understanding I can safely delete all the files/folders right? Re ur questions, what is still missing?